# While loop + Array load quicker / alternative

Tags: php, arrays

I have myself a small array which grabs information from the Twitch.tv and displays it using the variables in an array I have created.

```
<?php include 'header.php'; 

$streamers = array("NomadicTV","TheOneJat","greatbritishbg","Themastergamer94","Gecko194","slayus","skunkodor");
shuffle($streamers);
$random = shuffle($streamers);
$streamerscount = 0;
$streamtotal = count($streamers);

    while (list(, $val) = each($streamers)) {
        $url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/".$val;
         $json = file_get_contents($url);
         $json = json_decode($json);
         $stream =  $json->stream;
                $channelAPI = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/'. $val));
                $status     = $channelAPI->status;
                $name       =  $channelAPI->display_name;
                $gameimg    = "http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/".$channelAPI->game . "-272x380.jpg";
                $viewers    = $streamsAPI->stream->viewers;
                $followers  = $channelAPI->followers;
                $views      = $channelAPI->views;
                $avatar     = $channelAPI->logo;


                    echo    '<a href="cast.php?caster='.$val.'"/><img src="' . $avatar . '" class="streamers"/></a>';

    }
?>
```

My issue is that when the page loads it takes a while as it runs through the while list. Is there an alternative for this which will make my page load quicker?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could cache your result in a file, e.g:

```
$cacheFile = 'path/to/cache/folder/' . md5(serialize($shuffle));
$age = time() - filemtime(cacheFile);
$maxAge = 3600; // 1 hour
if(file_exists($cacheFile) && $age < $maxAge) {
  echo file_get_contents($cacheFile);
} else {
  ob_start();
  /* here comes your loop */
  $output = ob_get_clean();
  file_put_contents($cacheFile, $output);
  echo $output;
}
```

- of course the webserver needs write permissions in the cache folder. You could use `sys_get_temp_dir()` for that.
- this is only a good solution if the caching mechanism (md5, file I/O,
  ...) ist much faster then your loop, you should benchmark it.
- Code is untested, but I think it illustrates the concept.